# quickly search for very rare field in a huge mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, query-performance

I have a huge collection with ~1 billion documents, very few of those documents (less then 200) contain some field "`rare_field`".

How can I, as quickly as possible find all documents containing that field?

If I simply do:

```
collection.find({ "rare_field" : { $exists : true }})
```

it times out.
This might take days to complete, so I'm not sure that even preventing timeout via a query flag will help here, but maybe I'm wrong.

I can also write a script to go over all documents but this will be slow as it'll need to pass all 1 billions documents over the wire to my server, I want some solution that will not require any passing of data on the wire, and will be quick.

Notes: this is a `sharded` collection.

*I'll post my current solution as an answer, but I'm not sure it's 100% correct, and it's not as fast as I want it.*

Comment: put this `rare-field` in your sharding query! and because of it, mongo would index this field too! so it's gonna be fast!

Comment: thanks. this is a one time thing, so I don't really need an index here.
this might have been a good solution when the db was empty, but indexing this field now would take a lot of time, just like going over all docs manually (i think)

Comment: you're right about the time consumption! so it's totally up to ur application! another way is to keep the result in cache! store the result in a new collection or in redis or smtn!

Comment: create a [sparse index](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-sparse/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without an index on `rare-field`, in the worst case, mongodb will need to go over all documents in the collection. In such a case the cursor may time out, so you need to add a flag to the cursor to prevent it from doing so.

In the mongo shell, this would mean a query like:

```
var cursor = db.collection.find({ "rare_field" : { $exists : true }}).noCursorTimeout();
```

If your concern is that network problems or other issues will interrupt the query before the cursor has been populated with [batchSize](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.batchSize/) matching documents, then you can indeed get the documents one by one as you suggested in your answer, however you'll need to sort by `{ _id: 1 }`, and use `noCursorTimeout()` and `limit(1)`, i.e.:

```
var doc = db.collection.find({ "rare_field" : { $exists : true }})
            .sort({ _id: 1 })
            .limit(1)
            .noCursorTimeout()
            .next();
```

Then as you suggested, retrieve the next document by repeating the query while adding the condition `{ _id: { $gt: doc._id } }` to the query object.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use `findOne` instead of find:

```
var doc = collection.findOne({ "rare_field" : { $exists : true }});
```

and then loop to get the next one:

```
var doc = collection.findOne({ _id : { $gt : doc._id}, "rare_field" : { $exists : true }});
```

However, I'm not 100% sure that these calls must give me results ordered by `_id`, and I'm not sure that single `findOne` won't timeout as well.

I fear that explicitly adding `sort({_id : 1})` will force the query to get all results, and then to deliver the first one.

Comment: I don't think this would be a good idea! like you're doing the worst thing ever! you're mongo would do the same thing as `find({ "rare_field" : { $exists : true }});` would do! but you're breaking it into several pieces with a lot of overhead!

Comment: also your fear is kinda explain why you shouldn't do this!:)